# JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

Tags: python

have below json, in string format

```
ip = ('"{"transform_pp": {"name": "ken",'
     '"location": "paris"},'
    '"transform_zz": {"name": "pen",'
     '"location": "paris"}}"')

json.loads(ip)
```

but getting below error

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 (char 3)
```

want to know, what's wrong in `ip`, that its this giving error ?

I know, `json.loads('{}','{}')`, not allowed, but how its happening in `ip` ? And how can I fix this `ip`, because dont have control over which produces this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `"` quotes _around_ the object `{}` (`"{...}"`)? That is conflicting with the legitimate quotes inside the object and seems pointless anyway.

Comment: If you wanted the string to be JSON that itself represents a string, then the quotes inside the represented string need to be escaped, in order to not conflict with the quotes used by the JSON format to indicate that a string is being represented. If you wanted the string to be JSON that represents a dict, then the string contents should not have quotes around the outside.

Answer (score 1):

The data provided is a bit cumbersome with backticks please modify it to below

```
import json

ip = ('{"transform_pp": {"name": "ken", "location": "paris"},'
      '"transform_zz": {"name": "pen", "location": "paris"}}')

data = json.loads(ip)
print(data)
```

output:

```
{'transform_pp': {'name': 'ken', 'location': 'paris'}, 'transform_zz': {'name': 'pen', 'location': 'paris'}}
```